# Insertion of BLOB fails with the file being NULL

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, blob

In Java, with JDBC I am trying to insert a file in a BLOB column in a table of an Oracle database.

Here is how I proceed:

```
private Statement getStatement(File f, String fid, Long dex, String uid, int id)
{
  FileInputStream fis = null;
  PreparedStatement statement;
  try
  {
    statement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO BLOBTABLE (FID, FDEX, SFILE, UID, ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    statement.setString(1, fid);
    statement.setLong(2, dex);
    fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    statement.setBinaryStream(3, fis, file.length());
    statement.setString(4, uid);
    statement.setInt(5, id);
  }
  finally
  {
    if (fis != null)
      fis.close();
  }
  return statement;
}

private insertStuff()
{
  File f = new File("/home/user/thisFileExists");
  PreparedStatement statement = getStatement(f, "XYZ", 18L, "ABC", 78);
  statement.execute();
}
```

When the .execute is run, I get an Oracle error:

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("ORACLEUSER"."BLOBTABLE"."SFILE")
```

SFILE is the BLOB column. So this means the database at the end of the chain receives NULL in the query.

How come?

If I replace:

```
statement.setBinaryStream(3, fis, file.length());
```

With:

```
statement.setBinaryStream(3, new ByteArrayInputStream(("RANDOMSTRING".getBytes())));
```

It works so *it* somehow does not like my file stream.

Is it a problem that I close the stream? that is how they do it on all samples I saw.

Comment: Insert `''` an empty string instead of `null` in case of `BLOB` type  column.

Comment: Aside from anything else - there's no need for the "Yoda condition" of `if (null != stream)`. Just use `if (stream != null)`, which most people will find more readable.

Answer (score 2):

You're closing the `FileInputStream` before you execute the statement, so there's no way for the statement to get the data when it actually needs it. It would better to pass an `InputStream` into your method, so you can close it *externally* after the statement has executed:

```
private insertStuff() {
    File file = new File("/home/user/thisFileExists");
    try (InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        PreparedStatement statement = getStatement(stream, "XYZ", 18L, "ABC", 78);
        statement.execute();
    }
}
```

... where `getStatement` would accept an `InputStream` instead of the `File`, and use the overload of `setBinaryStream` which doesn't take a data length. Alternatively, you could pass in the `File` and it could open the stream, create the statement, execute the statement, then close the stream.

As a side note, you should be closing the statement using a try-with-resource or try/finally statement, too.

Comment: Passing the length isn't really necessary: just passing the stream should be sufficient when using `setBinaryStream(int, InputStream)` instead

Comment: Yes, no longer closing the stream before the execution prevents the insert from failing overall, but it inserts a 0-bytes BLOB which is not better,...

Comment: @tisek: That sounds like a separate issue then. Are you sure you haven't read from the stream that you're passing in? That's the only explanation I can think of. You might want to ask a new question with a short but complete example of your new code demonstrating the problem - which can all be in a single method, of course, for simplicity. No need for a separate class. Stack Overflow doesn't work well with questions which evolve over time.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the `FileInputStream` before the database has used it. The JDBC driver is allowed to defer consumption of the stream until the actual execute.

Also note that your test comparison with a fixed string isn't entirely fair: it isn't the same method overload so it might be that one works and the other one doesn't (although that isn't the case here).